# Loop each variable into SAS macro

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I have several variables in data set survey. I want to write a loop to load each variable into a SAS macro.

the code is below.

```
%let var= r1 r2 r3 ; 

DATA survey; 
   INPUT id sex $ age inc r1 r2 r3 ; 
   DATALINES; 
 1  F  35 17  7 2 2 
17  M  50 14  5 5 3 
33  F  45  6  7 2 7 
49  M  24 14  7 5 7 
65  F  52  9  4 7 7 
81  M  44 11  7 7 7 
2   F  34 17  6 5 3 
18  M  40 14  7 5 2 
34  F  47  6  6 5 6 
50  M  35 17  5 7 5 
; 

%MACRO bvars(input);

proc univariate data = "D:\hsb2" plots;
var &input.;
run;

%MEND bvars;
```

I just want &var can load into macro bvars each time for only one variable instead of writing the following.

```
%bvars(r1)
%bvars(r2)
%bvars(r3)
.....
```

This is time consuming while the number of variables are bigger than 100.

Comment: If you don't specify a var statement proc univariate will run for all numeric variables. Or try var _numeric_ for all numeric variables. That numeric should have an underscore before and after but SO is eating it :(

Comment: That sort of useful but not really either, going through that much output manually would be painful, what are you really after in the end?

Answer (score 1):

This will run `proc univariate` for all the variables in survay which start with "r" (so r1, r2, etc.). Procedures with a `var` statement usually accept multiple variables.

```
proc univariate data = survey;
    var r:;
run;
```

If you wish to run for all numeric variables replace `r:` with `_NUM_`.

If you want to loop through the variables and call a function seperately each time there are several approaches. Usually they involve a macro do loop (which must be inside a macro) like so:

```
%macro looper(inData);
    /* List all the variable names */
    proc contents data = &inData. out = _colNames noprint;
    run;
    proc sql noprint;
        select name 
        /* Put the variable names in a macro variable list */
        into :colNames separated by " "
        from _colNames
        /* Get only numeric variables */
        where type = 1
        order by varnum;
    quit;
    /* Loop through the variable names */
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&colNames.));
        %let colName = %scan(&colNAmes., &i.);
        %put &colName.;
        /* Your macro call or code here */
        /* %bvars(&inData., &colName.) */
    %end; 
%mend looper;
%looper(sashelp.cars);
```

It might prove useful for you to become familiar with macro `%do` loops, `proc contents` (or better yet `proc datasets`), the `%scan()` function and the different ways to assign macro variables. The sas documentation online is a great place to start.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated answer.**

You can utilise the VCOLUMN table that is automatically created for every SAS dataset in each library including the Work library. This table contains a row for each variable for each dataset in SAS.

So you would do the following. I am assuming your survery dataset is in the Work library.

So the code does the following;
1. Looks ups your dataset in the Vcolumn table and only keep the name of the variable (thats all we need) and store it into dataset temp.
2. For every variable run the bvars Marcro via the call execute statement.

```
data temp(keep=name);
set Sashelp.Vcolumn;
where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'SURVEY';
run;

*Call macro using call execute;
data _null_;
set temp;
call execute ("%bvars("||name||");");
run;
```

Comment: I run it, but it doesn't work. Can you try other method instead of using Vcolumn? Because the survey data is just a testing data set. Thanks!

Comment: You can run it on testing data sets also. Go to Sashelp directory and then look at the Vcolumn table and check if your data set is appearing in the table.

Comment: There is no data set called SURVEY. Can you write the full code for me to get a sense of that?

Comment: Try running your data survey code from original code first. All my code is doing is looking up your data set called 'survey' which you stated in your question in the VCOLUMN table.

Comment: ERROR: Variable libname is not on file SASHELP.VCOLUMN.

Comment: If you navigate to the Sashelp folder in SAS - do you see a VCOLUMN data set?

Comment: Unfortunately this is unlikely to work. Macro code is resolved before base sas code. Therefore, the `%bvars` macro will write out a `proc univariate` inside the data step and the variable name will not be replaced by its values as you were hoping.

Comment: If i ouput to a data set first then loop through that data set with the macro then it should resolve that problem. @ArchStanton

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Macros are in general resolved into base SAS code before any base SAS code is run. If you want to delay the macro resolution until the data step is running you can use `call execute()` but I would not recommend that for calling a prov step as it would be run inside the data step and might have unexpected behavior. For completeness you'd want `call execute('%bvars('||name||')')`.